# Excluding certain template or pages from translation

Tags: wordpress, translation

Is it possible to exclude a certain template or pages from not just not being translated but being reverted to the original default language slug altogether as if there was no translation at all?

Running on Wordpress platform. Translation plugin used is "Transposh". Thank you.

Comment: This plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years - don't use crap like this

Comment: I know but unfortunately I started my project with this plugin and I can't export my manual translations to another plugin from Transposh so I'd have to start over from scratch.